# Array to string conversion in Error in magento 2 category app image upload in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, catalog

This is my code, I'm getting that error on line number 62

[image]

[image]

if, you faced this kind of error,please help me to resolve it

this is my code

```
if (!empty($category->getAppImage())) {
                unset($result[$category->getId()]['app_image']);
                $result[$category->getId()]['app_image'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('app_image');
                $appimg = false;
                if ($category->getAppImage()!='NULL' && $category->getAppImage()!='') {
                  
                    $appimg = $mediaurl.'catalog/category/'.$category->getAppImage();
                    $result[$category->getId()]['app_image'][0]['url'] =$appimg;
                } else { 
                         $result[$category->getId()]['app_image'][0]['url'] =$appimg;
                }
                
            }
```

> Print Array Result

```
[{"name":"imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png","type":"image\/png","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpkARH8r","error":"0","size":"34171","path":"\/var\/www\/html\/stagingapp.nejree.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/tmp\/category","file":"imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png","url":"https:\/\/\/media\/catalog\/tmp\/category\/imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png","cookie":{"name":"admin","value":"s3jbpiubqq13tsrase0d4e6cma","lifetime":"900000","path":"\/nback","domain":"stagingappadmin.nejree.com"},"previewType":"image"}]
```

Comment: what is value of $category->getAppImage();?

Comment: it's an array value

Comment: Can you please print at array value in question?

Comment: i edit my quation and add print array in my quation

Comment: Did you get your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error return because of you use direct array value as a string.

**Solution :**

You need to decode this json array :

Add this below code in your construct :

```
protected $jsonSerializer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer
) {
    $this->jsonSerializer = $jsonSerializer;
}
```

After that, use this below code in your function.

```
$jsonString = '[
{
    "name":"imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png",
    "type":"image\/png",
    "tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpkARH8r",
    "error":"0",
    "size":"34171",
    "path":"\/var\/www\/html\/stagingapp.nejree.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/tmp\/category",
    "file":"imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png",
    "url":"https:\/\/\/media\/catalog\/tmp\/category\/imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png",
    "cookie":
    {
        "name":"admin",
        "value":"s3jbpiubqq13tsrase0d4e6cma",
        "lifetime":"900000",
        "path":"\/nback",
        "domain":"stagingappadmin.nejree.com"
    },
    "previewType":"image"
}
]';
$array = $this->jsonSerializer->unserialize($jsonString);
print_r($array);
```

You will get an array. Then, you can use the value that you want.

**For eg :** $array[0]['name']

**Output :** imgpsh_fullsize_anim_14.png

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in below code

```
 $appimg = $mediaurl.'catalog/category/'.$category->getAppImage();
```

Please print the value ($category->getAppImage()) if it is an array then it will create issue.